# Background will not extend 100% to left of box when it is animated to increase in size

Tags: css, hover, jquery-animate, size, css-animations

I am trying to get a box to expand in size whilst leaving the text centred. My problem is: the background I have used in the title section of the box will not extend 100% to the left when the box expands.

I think this may have to do with the following code, where in 'hover mode' I have put -5px for margin left and top so that the box expands from the middle (that is because width and height expand by 10px):

```
.serviceBox1 {
        width:290px;
        height:282px;
        position:absolute;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden ;
        }

            .serviceBox1Hover {
                width:300px;
                height:292px;
                margin-left: -5px; 
                margin-top: -5px;
                }
```

See the following for rest of code, and example:

https://jsfiddle.net/L9oohws1/

N.b. The solution must ensure the text stays in the middle of the box when it is enlarged, as in the fiddle above. Simply changing width to 100% makes the text move to the left in relation to the middle of the box (when it has been expanded).

Comment: By the way, `background-color:none` is an error. You meant `background-color:transparent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `width:290px;` to `width:100%;`. and remove the `width` of `#textArea` and `#headingArea`

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/L9oohws1/4/)

```
.serviceBox1Text {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that the text then moves left in relation to the box. If you look at the original fiddle I posted, the text stays in the middle.

Comment: @JonnyBoy Please, check the above link again.

Comment: @JonnyBoy Is that helpful?

Comment: Almost. The only problem is that the text reformats  when the box increases in size - I have edited your fiddle to show this: https://jsfiddle.net/L9oohws1/13/ . See how "katirpied" changes lines.... anyway to stop this?

Comment: That's it. How did you do it?

Comment: I gave fixed width(260px) to the `#servicesDescriptionBoxes p` to prevent from stretching it.

Answer (score 2):

```
        .serviceBox1Text {
            width:100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

Change the width to 100%.  This will cause it to extend the fully to the left on hover.

Comment: @urnostam The only problem with this solution is that the text then moves left in relation to the box. If you look at the original fiddle I posted, the text stays in the middle.